# Discord.js Splitting embed description

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a simple command that adds player name, class, status and tag to my database. This is the first step of this command. Second, print all this data in embed description. I did it, everything works fine until I reached the length limit.

I found a solution - to split the message from Discord Util. But, I can't make it work, I get an error *DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message*. Requesting help.

I will attach an image of what the data looked like before I ran into the limit

Code:

```
if (interaction.commandName === 'roster_add') {
            if (interaction.member.roles.cache?.has('945613899716247563')) {
                    var playerName = interaction.options.getString('ign');
                    var playerClass = interaction.options.getString('class');
                    var playerTag = interaction.options.getMentionable('tag');
                    var playerStatus = interaction.options.getString('status');

                    // create player in db
                    const addplayer = await heavenMembers.create({
                        ign: playerName,
                        class: playerClass,
                        tag: playerTag,
                        status: playerStatus,
                    })
                        // get all members from db
                        var memberList = await heavenMembers.findAll({ attributes: ['id','ign', 'class', 'tag', 'status'], raw:true })
                        //format data
                        var actualMembers = memberList.map(function(element){return `**ID:** ${element.id}\  **IGN:**\   ${element.ign}\  **Class:** ${element.class}\  **Tag:** ${element.tag}\  **Status:** ${element.status}`}).join('\r\n');
                        
                        // from here i'm stuck, 
                        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                        embed.setTitle(`Some title`)
                        embed.setColor('#0099ff')
                        if (actualMembers.length >= 2048) {
                            const ly = Util.splitMessage(actualMembers, {
                                maxLength: 1024,
                                char: '\n',
                                prepend: '',
                                append: '',
                            });
                            embed.setDescription(ly.shift());
                            ly.forEach((i) => embed.addField('\u200B', i));
                        }
                        else {
                        embed.setDescription(actualMembers);
                        }
                        interaction.channel.send(embed);
                } 
            
            else {
                interaction.reply(`${interaction.user.username}, you don't have permission`)
            }
            
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: "discord.js": "^13.6.0"

Comment: Then `.send(embed)` should be `.send({ embeds: [embed] })`

Comment: OMG, How did I miss it... it's time to rest. Thank you so much for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in  `interaction.channel.send(embed);` must be `interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })`
Thanks to Zsolt